# how can i validate the nested attributes field in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have two models

```
class Information < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :study
  validates_presence_of :email
end
```

and

```
class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :informations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :informations
end
```

I show up a form of study which contains few fields for the informations and i want to validate presence of those fields. Only on validation success i wanted to save the study field values as well and i wanted to show errors if the validation fails. How can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you still having trouble with this issue? If not, select/upvote an answer below, or post a new one with your own findings. If you still have an issue, please update your post with any necessary details

Answer (score 4):

You write validations in the models that you require, as normal. So if you need to validate presence of field `foo` in the `Information` class you'd just write `validates_presence_of :foo` in that class. Likewise validations for `Study` fields just go in the `Study` class. With nested attributes, when you update a `Study` instance from a `params` hash that contains nested attributes, it'll update the `Information` instance(s) too, running validations in passing. That's what the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` call is doing - it's giving "permission" for the appropriate bits of a `params` hash to be used in this way.

You can use `reject_if` to only reject *new* nested records should they fail to meet criteria. So I might let someone create a Study and only create one or more nested Information instances associated with that Study if they'd filled in field(s) in the form, but if they left them blank, the nested stuff wouldn't be created and saved (so you don't get pointless blank associated records). The Study would still be saved. For example:

```ruby
accepts_nested_attributes_for(
  :informations,
  reject_if: proc() { | attrs | attrs[ 'title' ] .blank? }
)
```

This and more is covered in the API documentation here:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Beware that nested fields are intended for *existing records only*. If you were creating a *new* Study instance in a `new`/`create` action with no Information instances associated, you won't see any nested form fields for your Information class at all - when you might be expecting just one, for a blank new item. This can be very confusing if you aren't ready for it! You'll need to manually add a new `Information` instance to your `Study` instance in the controller or similar for the 'new' and 'create' actions, e.g. using `before_filter :create_blank_object, only: [ :new, :create ]`, with, say:

```
def create_blank_object
  @study = Study.new
  @study.informations << Information.new
end
```

Comment: I am not sure but i thought the reject_if will not save the nested attributes only but it would save the study field values.

Comment: Oops, I've been misleading about reject_if. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Answer (score -1):

you can use validates_presence validation available in rails other wise you can write `before_create` or `before_save callback` method. write `validation logic` inside the `before_create` or `before_save` callback method.

Comment: I have used validates_presence_of :email in the information model and what i look for is validating the information fields on saving the study. Hope you will understand it now.

Comment: before going to store these new fields we can validates those by using before_create or before_save method right?, so use any one method and write your logic

Answer (score -2):

Check out the API Doc for [validates_associated](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated):

> Validates whether the associated object or objects are all valid. Works with any kind of association.

If you call a method on the parent object which runs validations (e.g. save), the validation on the associated objects will be called as well.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).