# Restore Rails callbacks after save(validate:false)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rather complex business logic in a model with associations. I want to allow users to save incomplete (invalid) models for future completion. In my controller, I therefore call `instance.save(validate: false)`.

Here are the 3 models, that I have extracted from my application.
The models may seen overblown, since I extracted only the relevant part.

1) `Container` model:

```
class Container < ApplicationRecord
    Languages = %w(fr en de it es)

    belongs_to :name, class_name: "Name", foreign_key: :name_id

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :name

    validates :name, presence: true

    # create an empty model 
    def self.create_new
        c = Container.new

        c.name = Name.new
        c.name.save
        Languages.each do |l|
            c.name.translations << NameItem.new(language: l, text: "")
        end # Languages.each do |l|

        c.description = Description.new
        c.description.save
        Languages.each do |l|
            c.description.translations << DescriptionItem.new(language: l, text: "")
        end # Languages.each do |l|

        c
    end 
end
```

2) `Name` model:

```
class Name < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :translations, class_name: "NameItem", foreign_key: :parent_id

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations
end
```

3) `NameItem` model:

```
class NameItem < ApplicationRecord
    validates :language, presence: true
    validate  :text_validation

    private
    def text_validation
        return if language.nil?

        errors.add(:text, :blank_text, language: language) if text.nil? || text.size == 0
    end
end
```

Given the following sequence of instructions, I am at a loss why the last instruction (`instance.valid?`) returns true. It seems to me that the validation callbacks are disabled, but I'm not sure this is the proper diagnostic. Could this be related to the use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ?:

```
# create an invalid model (since empty)
instance = Container.create_new

# check that this instance is invalid
instance.valid? # returns false, this is the expected behavior

# save the model, skipping the validations
instance.save(validate: false)

# now instance.valid? will always return true, because it will
# skip the validations. How can I restore the callbacks ?
instance.valid? # returns true, but this is not the desired behavior,
                # hence my question
```

I tried to disable and re-enable the callbacks with instructions like the following, but to no avail.

```
[:create, :save, :update].each do |action|
  Container.skip_callback(action)
end

[:create, :save, :update].each do |action|
  Container.set_callback(action)
end
```

**So my question is:** after having invoked `instance.save(validate: false)`, what instructions do I need to run so that `instance.valid?` does indeed perform the validation checks again and return false ?

Comment: If a user can create a Record without filling some attributes, then you should not validate their presence at all, not at the creation event. BUT, maybe later in the Record's life cycle, when, let's say, the user wants to publish this record (or use it, check it as "completed", whatever), then the validation must be made.

Comment: Thank you @MrYoshiji. Could you please propose a code snippet fulfilling this purpose ?

Comment: In your app, at what moment (event) your Container **needs** to check the presence of the attributes? Maybe when a user want to use a Container in a certain context, those available containers must have the attrs present,right?

Comment: There can be 2 solutions I see so far. **Option 1** would be to have to models, Container and PublishedContainer (or ValidContainer, FilledContainer, etc.) and each model would have its own validations. You could use Single Table Inheritance in that case so you won't duplicate the tables and the data. **Option 2** would be a simple instance method `publish` or `declare_as_ready_to_use` which validates the presence of all the needed attrs and then set a value (DateTime equal to when the user decided to publish the record, better than just a boolean) OR returns errors for each missing attribute.

Comment: @MrYoshiji - thanks for your contribution, I really appreciate it. I had not throught about Single Table Inheritance, this is something I need to investigate and I am grateful for the idea. What I have done right now is to isolate the validation logic in my own method, that I can call whenever I want. It is quite sad though that I could not use the Rails validations, which would have meant less code.

Comment: Hi @Albert, updated my answer with a link to something that should help you.

Comment: Hi @Matt and THANK YOU for digging deeper into the issue I am facing. I accepted your answer and +1ed your comment. This is it ! I will use the Option 2 proposed by MrYoshiji to code the features I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `save(validate: false)` doesn't leave callbacks turned off, you must have some other code that runs after save that makes the record pass validation.

Check your `before/after_save` callbacks, and maybe post the model.

Edit:

Using nested attributes for new records will give you validation trouble, it really works best with existing records as the association doesn't exist properly on a new record. There's a good explanation of this and a workaround in the last paragraph of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22471747/385532).

Comment: Thank you & +1 for your hint. I updated the question. The `before/after_save` callbacks do not hold anything special as fas as my experience with Rails goes. I would rather suspect the problem is related with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but my search in Google did not turn up any solution to my problem.

Comment: Hi Albert, updated my answer with a link to something that should help you.